# Which the best programming language to handle time series?

Tags: time-series, software

I work with CSV files containing 10-minute data of temperatures of some years of a station, and I usually perform some calculations: mean, average, correlations between two stations, correlations in different seasons, correlations day/night, ...

I program this calculations by using plain Python or Microsoft Excel VBA, by using loops and simple calculations. It's not very hard to code, but I wonder if there is a Python library or any other programming environment which helps me to save time and lines of code.

I've heard about ScyPy and R, and I would be very grateful if you could share any experience with these tools.

Answer (score 12):

Both Python and R are excellent choices for this type of work.

If you are already using Python, then the easiest option might be to start using [Numerical Python](https://numpy.org/) (NumPy). [The tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) provides a basic introduction. For further pointers, see the top answer to [numpy: learning resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375094/numpy-learning-resources).

If you are interested in learning R, the following thread provides lots of pointers: [Books for learning the R language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192369/books-for-learning-the-r-language).

Comment: Check out the Pandas library if you go with Python.

Answer (score 5):

If you wind up using R, check out the FDA package. It will help you turn those repeat observations into functional data (i.e. smooth curves), opening up a variety of interesting modes of analysis.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fda/index.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis